# How to add a Date Value and a Time Value together in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a Power Apps application with two controls, a DatePicker which returns a Date Value, and a Component which returns a Time Value (Power Apps does not yet offer a Time Picker, and Date Picker ONLY sets a date).

So, I have the DATE value from one, and the TIME value from the other. How do I marry the two together? It should be as simple as

```
dtmMyDate.SelectedDate + compTimePicker.Value
```

But I get the error "This operation isn't valid on these types: Date, DateTime."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, I am adding the answer to help someone else later. The Component returns what LOOKS like a Time Value, but there is still a Date (1/1/1970) so you have to convert it to a TimeValue.

```
DateTimeValue(dtmMyDate.SelectedDate + TimeValue(compTimePicker.Value))
```

Using & " " & instead of + was a helpful suggestion I read, but the plus works fine.

Comment: You don't need the `DateTimeValue` in your expression - adding a date and a time value already return a date/time value. The DateTimeValue function converts a text to a date/time, so what it is doing is (implicitly) converting your date/time to a text, then converting it back to a date/time value. This is similar to what is happening with the call to TimeValue: it is converting the value from the component to a text, then parsing it to take the time value only.

Answer (score 0):

A component can only have a property with type 'Date and time' - just time is not available today. To retrieve the time only part of that component, to be able to add to your date, you can use something like

```
dtmMyDate.SelectedDate +
    Time(
        Hour(compTimePicker.Value),
        Minute(compTimePicker.Value),
        Second(compTimePicker.Value))
```